# Is $TM \cong M \times \mathbb{R}^n$ as sets?

Tags: differential-geometry

To be clear, I know these sets are not diffeomorphic or even homeomorphic in general. However, I've been told that there doesn't even exist a bijection between these sets.

But suppose $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold and let $\{\partial_1|_p, \ldots, \partial_n|_p\}$ be the basis of $T_p M$ with respect to some chart containing $p \in M$. If $v_p \in T_p M$ we have $v_p = v_p^i \partial_i|_p$ for unique real numbers $v_p^i$. Define the function $\lambda: TM \to M \times \mathbb{R}^n$ by $\lambda(p, v_p)=(p, v_p^1, \ldots, v_p^n)$.

Surely this is a well-defined bijection?

Comment: Yes, you have  well-defined bijection. Perhaps the claim was that there is no *natural* bijection? As you have demonstrated, it's possible to write a bijection once you choose a basis for each tangent space $T_pM$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that you can get a bijection by picking a basis for each tangent space.  Perhaps whoever claimed there was no such bijection meant that there was no *canonical* bijection (and so would exclude yours since it involves an arbitrary choice of basis for each tangent space).

(I would also remark that the existence of a bijection is an extremely weak condition.  Indeed, *every* positive-dimensional nonempty (second countable) manifold has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, so there are bijections between all of them.)

Comment: This bijection has the special property that it restricts to linear isomorphisms on the tangent spaces $T_p M$. So it's a little better than just picking a random bijection!

Comment: How can I verify your last remark about cardinality?

Answer (score 3):

Sure: The tangent bundle on $M^n$ is by definition the disjoint union (with a more complicated topology) of the $T_p M$ for $p\in M$, and each $T_p M$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space by definition. Of course, the isomorphisms $T_p M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are not canonical and can't be made continuous in $p$ for a nontrivial bundle, but that's not a problem if you're just looking for a map of sets.